# 403 error for loading font file CodeIgniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, fonts

Hello I am new to codeigniter. I am using the external font file for my site through css. Here is my css code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'ElegantIcons';
src:url('http://localhost/findacare/font/ElegantIcons.eot'),
    url('http://localhost/findacare/font/ElegantIcons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('http://localhost/findacare/font/ElegantIcons.woff') format('woff'),
    url('http://localhost/findacare/font/ElegantIcons.svg#ElegantIcons') format('svg'),
    url('http://localhost/findacare/font/ElegantIcons.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

But i'm getting the following error file when i load the file

```
GET http://localhost/findacare/font/ElegantIcons.woff 404 (Not Found) manage_profile:1
GET http://localhost/findacare/font/ElegantIcons.svg 404 (Not Found) /findacare/font/ElegantIcons.svg#ElegantIcons:1
GET http://localhost/findacare/font/ElegantIcons.ttf 404 (Not Found) /findacare/font/ElegantIcons.ttf:1
```

And my file structure is:

```
findacare-
          -application
          -css
          -font
          -images
```

I checked many times even by giving absolute path. Could any one please help me.

Comment: Your file structure says `fonts`; the 404 message is looking in `font`

Comment: sorry my file structure is font. i typed wrong

Comment: please post your `.htacces`. It is likely that you have a whitelist of folders in your htaccess and you haven't yet specified the font folder. One way to test this would be to move your font folder into the css folder and update the links accordingly. If it starts working, then thats a good indicator that your font folder hasn't been whitelisted yet.

Comment: I copied my font files directly to the css folder and changed the code accordingly that worked like a charm. Thank you for the reply. Can you please suggest me how to whitelist my font folder.

Comment: I wrote up a short answer explaining how to fix it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah thats really awesome but i didn't created any .htaccess file for my application. I'm simply using the downloaded folder of codeigniter

Comment: There is a `.htaccess` file in your webroot (the same directory as your `index.php`). I guarantee you it's there as your application won't work without it. The `.` dot format of files are hidden on some operating systems so you may need to show hidden files before you can open it.

Comment: I have added the font folder to the rewrite condition now i am able to directly access the font folder.. Thank you very much for your help..My problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in your `.htaccess` file you most likely have a line of code that looks something like this:

`RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|css/|js/|images/)`

This is a white list of folders/files that won't be passed through your applications index.php. All other urls will be passed into the application.

Because your font folder is in the webroot, you need to add this folder to the whitelist so that it can be accessed by your css rules.

`RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|css/|js/|images/|font/)`

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by you in your file structure folder name is "fonts" and in your css source path you are using "font".

Comment: Thank you for the reply...Sorry my foler structure is "font" only..i typed by mistake..\

Answer (score 0):

I have used it like this in one of my project, if you have these lines in a `css` file inside the `css` folder then try this may help:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ElegantIcons';
    src:url('../font/ElegantIcons.eot'),
        url('../font/ElegantIcons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../font/ElegantIcons.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../font/ElegantIcons.svg#ElegantIcons') format('svg'),
        url('../font/ElegantIcons.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: then make sure that your folder is readable. Hit this link `http://localhost/findacare/font/ElegantIcons.eot` directly in your brower and see.